# Tensorflow Keras TypeError: Cannot instantiate typing_extensions.Concatenate

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm creating a model using Tensorflow and Keras, this is code I have copied from a tutorial, but I'm receiving this error:

TypeError: Cannot instantiate typing_extensions.Concatenate

This is the code that returns this error.

```
from numpy import zeros
from numpy import ones
from numpy.random import randn
from numpy.random import randint
from keras.datasets.cifar10 import load_data
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Reshape
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import Conv2DTranspose
from keras.layers import LeakyReLU
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import Embedding
from keras.layers import Concatenate
```

```
def define_discriminator(in_shape=(32,32,3), n_classes=10):
    
  # label input
  in_label = Input(shape=(1,))  #Shape 1
  # embedding for categorical input
  #each label (total 10 classes for cifar), will be represented by a vector of size 50. 
  #This vector of size 50 will be learnt by the discriminator
  li = Embedding(n_classes, 50)(in_label) #Shape 1,50
  # scale up to image dimensions with linear activation
  n_nodes = in_shape[0] * in_shape[1]  #32x32 = 1024. 
  li = Dense(n_nodes)(li)  #Shape = 1, 1024
  # reshape to additional channel
  li = Reshape((in_shape[0], in_shape[1], 1))(li)  #32x32x1


  # image input
  in_image = Input(shape=in_shape) #32x32x3
  # concat label as a channel
  merge = Concatenate()([in_image, li]) #32x32x4 (4 channels, 3 for image and the other for labels)

  # downsample: This part is same as unconditional GAN upto the output layer.
  #We will combine input label with input image and supply as inputs to the model. 
  fe = Conv2D(128, (3,3), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(merge) #16x16x128
  fe = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(fe)
  # downsample
  fe = Conv2D(128, (3,3), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(fe) #8x8x128
  fe = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(fe)
  # flatten feature maps
  fe = Flatten()(fe)  #8192  (8*8*128=8192)
  # dropout
  fe = Dropout(0.4)(fe)
  # output
  out_layer = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(fe)  #Shape=1

  # define model
  ##Combine input label with input image and supply as inputs to the model. 
  model = Model([in_image, in_label], out_layer)
  # compile model
  opt = Adam(lr=0.0002, beta_1=0.5)
  model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
  return model
```

```
# Test discriminator
test_disc = define_discriminator()
test_disc.summary()
```

Full error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-1ab255eec685> in <module>
      1 # Test discriminator
----> 2 test_disc = define_discriminator()
      3 test_disc.summary()

1 frames
/usr/lib/python3.7/typing.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    330 
    331     def __call__(self, *args, **kwds):
--> 332         raise TypeError(f"Cannot instantiate {self!r}")
    333 
    334     def __instancecheck__(self, obj):

TypeError: Cannot instantiate typing_extensions.Concatenate
```

I also tried to Concatante with the below code but receive the same error:

```
merge = Concatenate(in_image, li)
```

Comment: Which python and tensorflow versions do you have?

Comment: tf = 2.9.2keras = 2.9.0

Comment: I asked version of Python too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that replacing

```
merge = Concatenate()([in_image, li])
```

with

```
merge = tf.concat(([in_image, li]), axis=3)
```

fixes this.